# FORMAT function exceeding supported size of ORDER BY list of RANGE windows frame (error 8279)

Tags: sql, sql-server

When it comes to displaying the year-month of my dates on SQL Server, I like using this solution:

```
format(year(<my_date>), '0000') + '-' + format(month(<my_date>), '00') as [year-month]
```

And I had nothing to complain about until recently.

But now I need to use that expression with a running total and things are getting trickier.

Here is what the data looks like:

```
ID |  date
> 
> 2514|2018-02-21
> 
> 0249|2018-02-21
> 
> 5122|2018-01-30
> 
> 7410|2018-02-15
> 
> 6638|2018-01-07
```

With the expected output:

```
> running total of count(ID) | year-month
> 
> 5|2018-02
> 
> 2|2018-01
```

As you can see, I want to get a running total of count(ID) over the whole set.

And here is my code:

```
SELECT DISTINCT  
count(id) over (partition by 1 order by format(year(<my_date>), '0000') + '-' + format(month(<my_date>), '00')),
format(year(<my_date>), '0000') + '-' + format(month(<my_date>), '00')

FROM my_table

ORDER BY format(year(<my_date>), '0000') + '-' + format(month(<my_date>), '00') desc
```

Or, to put it simply:

```
SELECT DISTINCT  
count(id) over (partition by 1 order by [year-month]),
[year-month]

FROM my_table

ORDER BY [year-month] desc
```

But it does not work because I always get the following error message:

> ORDER BY list of RANGE window frame has total size of 8000 bytes.
>   Largest size supported is 900 bytes.

My question is therefore twofold:

1. Why do I get this error message?
2. How can I fix this and get the result I want?

EDIT: I removed the second version of my code because I realized it was wrong.

Comment: Are you sure that you need running total? According to your expected output you are trying to `group + count`

Comment: If there are only two periods (Jan and Feb 2018 in my example), I want **count(ID's of first period)** for one line and **count(ID's of first period)+count(ID's of second period)** for the other one. I apologize if I was unclear with my initial introduction of the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're getting the message because SQL Server has no way of "knowing" how large the result of a `FORMAT` call can be and so is making the pessimistic assumption that it may be up to 8000 bytes.<sup>1</sup>

You *could* fix it by adding some `CAST` or `CONVERT` calls on the result. But I wouldn't.

I'd instead use the expression

```
DATEADD(month,DATEDIFF(month,0,<my date>),0)
```

This rounds off each date value to the 1st of their respective months. Yes, these expressions continue to have a day component but for *grouping*, *ordering* and *partitioning* purposes, that doesn't matter so long as they're equal.

Leave *string* formatting to where you actually need strings - at the final output stage, rather than doing string manipulations everywhere.

---

<sup>1</sup>And then the 900 bytes limitation is kicked in because that's the largest key size supported by SQL Server needs to perform sorting, which it may have to do to satisfy this part of the query.

Comment: OK I see. I did not realize the FORMAT function was so greedy. That means there is no way I will ever be able to use it with the example I gave (with a partition, I mean), right?

Comment: @Guillaume - well, as I alluded to in the second paragraph, you could insert explicit `CAST` or `CONVERT` calls around the format, giving SQL Server explicit size information, but in general I try to avoid working with strings if a more natural data type is available. Here, keeping the data as `datetime` means much less work for the server.

Answer (score 0):

U can try this :

```
SELECT
  COUNT(ID),
  concat(yea, '-0', mon)
FROM (SELECT
  company_id,
  YEAR(date) AS yea,
  MONTH(date) AS mon
FROM comdate) a
GROUP BY concat(yea, '-0', mon)
```